# Getting specific numbers in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to get 3 int values in a for loop connected with each other. What I basically want is this:

```
000
001
002
003
010
011
...
323
330
331
```

I want to have each of the 3 numbers in a variable starting from 0 and max 3 when it gets higher than 3 it increases the number left to it by 1

For example

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $array; $i++){
 echo $a . $b . $c . "<br />"; //Output would be the example I showed above
}
```

Comment: So you want a 3 digit counter in radix 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 63; $i++){
 $c = $i % 4;
 $b = ($i - $c)/4 % 4;
 $a = (($i - $c)/4 - $b)/4;
 echo $a . $b . $c . "<br />"; //Output would be the example I showed above
}
```

It's really just an explicit version of knittl's answer. The for loop has us step through every number from 0 thru 63, which happens to correspond with 0 through 333 in base 4. We then take $i, which is in base 10, and convert it to base 4 step by step. The % is the modulo operator - it returns the remainder after division. The least significant char is simply the remainder of $i/4, so we save that as $c. The next char is the 4 place (like the 10 place in base 10). So we subtract $c, which is already accounted for and divide by 4 and do the same thing.

Comment: Depends on the user's application. Since I don't know if there's an underlying data structure here - he mentions an array but doesn't present it - it would be easy enough to replace the `4`s with the maximum dimension of the array and `63` with `$x*$y*$z-1`, if that's what he's trying to do.

Comment: I really don't understand what exactly you do here but it works perfectly xD

Comment: Then I'll explain it! It's really just an explicit version of knittl's answer. The for loop has us step through every number from 0 thru 63, which happens to correspond with 0 through 333 in base 4. We then take `$i`, which is in base 10, and convert it to base 4 step by step. The `%` is the modulo operator - it returns the remainder after division. The least significant char is simply the remainder of `$i/4`, so we save that as `$c`. The next char is the `4` place (like the `10` place in base 10). So we subtract `$c`, which is already accounted for and divide by `4` and do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you that makes it clearer! Both answers work nice and work like I want! No idea on which would be better to use

Comment: @Dan I think you should add the comment ot the answer, just copy it there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`base_convert`](http://php.net/base_convert) to convert between arbitrary bases, in your case base 4.

```
for($i=0, $max = base_convert(333, 4, 10); $i < $max; ++$i) {
  echo base_convert($i, 10 , 4);
}
```

---

To get 0-padded output, use printf with a format specifier:

```
printf('%03d', base_convert($i, 10 , 4));
```

Comment: OP wants 0 padded output, doesn't he?

Comment: Zero padding isn't hard, just add a `printf`. You don't need nested loops to get zero padding.

Comment: Thank you this seems like the perfect answer I will try out the printf!

Comment: That does work but not the way I want. I want the 3 digits seperately stored in a variable

Comment: @Xegano: why do you need them in single variables? And what speaks against accessing the single digits as substrings? (store the base_converted string in a variable first, then `$s[0]` for the first digit).

Comment: `$tmp = str_split(base_convert($i, 10 , 4));`

Comment: Or even `list($a, $b, $c) = str_split(base_convert($i, 10, 4));`

Answer (score 1):

```
for($a = 0; $a <= 3; $a++){
 for($b = 0; $b <= 3; $b++){
    for($c = 0; $c <= 3; $c++){
       echo $a . $b . $c . "<br />";
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is working but this is suicidal. Use brain and you can do it in a single loop.

Comment: Indeed this is what I want but would be awesome in one loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$count = 20; //how many numbers do you want
for($i =0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo str_pad(base_convert($i, 10, 4),3,'0' , STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br/>';
}
```

`base_convert()` converts every $i value from 10 base to 4.

`str_pad()` fill it with '0' to given length (3 here).

`STR_PAD_LEFT` means that zeros should be added on left side.